# I would like to execute javascript from ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know how to do, to execute Javascript loaded inside an ajax page.
That's my loaded ajax page : https://jsfiddle.net/4dsbry7j/

JS :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/ajax/find2.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
function myFunction(response) {
"<center>"
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out +=
        "<a href='gallery.html'><img src='" + arr[i].avatar + "' style='max-height: 32%; max-width: 32%'/></a>" +
        arr[i].username + "<br> </br>"
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("gps").innerHTML = out;
}
"</center>"
```

When i load it, nothing appears... How can i do?

Thank you,
Alexis

Comment: There aren't too many browsers left that allow ajax calls on local files. Have you tried uploading it to the server and seeing what happens?

Comment: @lucas He **is** using a server. See the second line.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the code:

```
function myFunction(response) {
"<center>" // Wrong syntax. Remove that.
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
```

Please remove the line marked above. The syntax is wrong and it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, but that's doesn't work neither as loaded ajax page. I know that extern Javascript can't be execute in AJAX loaded page, false?

Comment: @AlexisGiuseppe Are you okay to use jQuery? If so I have a better solution with me. I am writing it for you.

Comment: @AlexisGiuseppe Tell me what's gonna come out as response from the PHP. Also it would be nice if you tell what is expected to happen with your code.

Comment: I want that : http://www.mon-application.com/questions/ajax/gallery.html  (Picture with text : "Alexis").  You can check http://www.mon-application.com/questions/ajax/index.html  and click on Gallery  (resize your browser screen as smartphone screen).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use center tag then use like

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var out ="<center>"
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out +="<a href='gallery.html'><img src='" + arr[i].avatar + "' style='max-height: 32%; max-width: 32%'/></a>" +
            arr[i].username + "<br> </br>"
        }
        out += "</table></center>";
        document.getElementById("gps").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's doesn't work neither as loaded ajax page. I know that extern Javascript can't be execute in AJAX loaded page, false?

Comment: I have an index page with <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> when i click on it, i am on the ajax loaded page "http://localhost/ajax/#!/gallery.html" but the function said above doesn't work. It's like if the Javascript is avoided.

Comment: call ajax on onLoad event

Comment: Now it's working when i reload the AJAX loaded page but not when i come from index.html. Do you want that i publish for you, to see?

Comment: That's what i have, i can't load Gallery.html page : http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/index.html

Comment: ?? Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: your gps id not found on page   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Yes, but how can i add this DIV 'GPS' inside the index.html for the page gallery.html? because the DIV is correctly found on http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/gallery.html ? :(

Comment: you want to view gallery in index.html page?

Comment: Mmmm, yes by AJAX. How can i load DIV "gps" inside ajax loaded page?

Comment: <div id="gps" onload="myFunction();" class="page-content"></div> add this in gallery.html page whereever you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that div is already on gallery.html (http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/gallery.html) everything is working on this page. But http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/index.html is loading gallery.html (this same file) by ajax (when you click on top left ligns, then Gallery) div disappear ?

Comment: It is very difficult to explain :-(

Comment: I edited my script to explain you more simply : go to http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/gallery.html (the alert & text is show). Go to http://mon-application.com/questions/ajax/index.html#!/gallery.html (the text is show but not the alert)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("gps").innerHTML = out;`

there does not appear to be an element with the ID of "gps" - at least that's what the console says

Comment: Hello Lucas, that's ok : It's working http://www.mon-application.com/questions/ajax/gallery.html but the JS on this page is not working on index.html AJAX.  http://www.mon-application.com/questions/ajax/index.html (resize the webpage as Smartphone screen) then click on the up left button and click on Gallery. it's loading gallery.html, but nothing appear... only title and no javascript.